# Fulltext search only returns exact matches

Tags: mysql

I have the following script

```
select c.id 
from ".TBL_COUPONS." as c 
inner join ".TBL_BUSINESS." as b 
on c.business_id = b.business_id 
inner join ".TBL_BLOCATION." as l 
on c.business_id = l.business_id 
where 
(match(c.name) against ('$search') 
    or 
match (b.name,b.category,b.subcat) against ('$search')) 
and l.zip = '$zip'
```

why would this only return exact matches?  For example, if i $search for locksmith nothing  comes up.
but if i search for locksmiths I'd get two results. (both searches included $zip = '75061')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to replace the last few characters with a wild card and do the MATCH () AGAINST in boolean mode

The search term "locksmith" should be changed in php  to "locksmith*" and your code would be something like this

```
match(c.name) against ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

For general purposes you should remove 's', 'ed', 'ing', etc. from the words in the original search term and add the wild card * to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is your table ok with the [fulltext restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)?

Comment: is Latin 1 a multi-byte char set?

Answer (score 0):

This is just how full text match works. It doesn't know about plurals and matches entire words. The issue comes up from time to time. Occasionally when you see a generated suggestion "Did you mean ..." it's a page trying to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Should I use LIKE then?  I need variants.