# match against shows only exact matches or matches data with some suffix not prefix, in MySQL fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql

I have already searched online but not find any use full link [Fulltext search only returns exact matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360992/fulltext-search-only-returns-exact-matches)

I have column posttitle with row values

```
shiva
goodshiva
goodshiva
goodshivagood
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE match(posttitle) against('shiva' in boolean mode)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE match(posttitle) against('*shiva*' in boolean mode)
```

doesn't return any value

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE match(posttitle) against('shiva*' in boolean mode)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE match(posttitle) against('+shiva*' in boolean mode)
```

shows only shivagood and shiva

using natural language mode shows only exact match.

Is there any way without using like?

Answer (score 1):

You have found a limitation to mysql full text search.

There is no equivalent syntax to

```
LIKE '%something%'
```

While MySQL itself will return a result for that type of query, no index can be used, so the table involved will be "table scanned"

The full text match syntax of +shiva* will only match when a word *starts* with shiva.  It will not match for words that contain shiva but do not start with shiva.

```
*shiva*
```

Is not supported.

Due to this limitation and other issues with full text search, many websites utilize an external search engine like sphinx or solr.  Sphinx for example, does allow for

```
'*shiva*'.
```